# Get the value selected from the dropdown selection which is fetch from the database to display table of the selected value

Tags: php, mysql

I have the selection option which is i fetch the data from the database. From the selection, I need to get the selected value in order to view the table to new page which it will view the table from the selected value.How i want to get the value from the select menu and display the table of the selected value?

Selection option
[image]
table for the selected value - display information from the selection

[image]

Comment: show us some code dude

Comment: Can you please share what you have did so far so we can help you more.

Comment: i want to add an image of my code but i cant.

Comment: i already have the selection option which i fetch from the database. if user select that value, it will direct to the new page which it display the table of  that selection value. How i want to get that selection value in order to display the table which relate to the value that user had select ?

Comment: is it difficult because the select option is fetch from the table from database ? so it is hard for me to get the selected value in order to display the table from the selection.